# Handling a multidimensional response object from REST API in Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, rest, dictionary, bitbucket-api

I am trying to handle a response object returned from BitBucket's API in Python. I have the following code to try and handle the response:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http:www.sampleurl.com'
myResponse = requests.get(url,auth=("myusername","mypassword"))

jd = myResponse.json()
print(jd.keys())
```

And the keys come back perfectly. However, within a particular key, a list is returned. I am interested in the values contained within that list. Specifically, I am concerned with the values within 'values'. Is there any way to parse out the information contained within values before/after is becomes a list?

My problem boils down to the fact I am having issues accessing information within the JSON Array 'parents' within the following sample response.

```
{
  "pagelen": 30,
  "values": [
    {
        hash: "61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466",
        links: {
            self: {
                href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/commit/61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466"
            },
            comments: {
                href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/commit/61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466/comments"
            },
            patch: {
                href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/patch/61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466"
            },
            html: {
                href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-rest/commits/61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466"
            },
            diff: {
                href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/diff/61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466"
            },
            approve: {
                href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/commit/61d9e64348f9da407e62f64726337fd3bb24b466/approve"
            }
        },
        repository: {
            links: {
                self: {
                    href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest"
                },
                avatar: {
                    href: "https://d3oaxc4q5k2d6q.cloudfront.net/m/bf1e763db20f/img/language-avatars/java_16.png"
                }
            },
            full_name: "atlassian/atlassian-rest",
            name: "atlassian-rest"
        },
        author: {
            raw: "Joseph Walton <jwalton@atlassian.com>",
            user: {
                username: "jwalton",
                display_name: "Joseph Walton",
                links: {
                    self: {
                        href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/jwalton"
                    },
                    avatar: {
                        href: "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/8e6e91101e3ed8a332dbebfdf59a3cef?d=https%3A%2F%2Fd3oaxc4q5k2d6q.cloudfront.net%2Fm%2Fbf1e763db20f%2Fimg%2Fdefault_avatar%2F32%2Fuser_blue.png&s=32"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        parents: [{
            hash: "59721f593b020123a75424285845325126f56e2e",
            links: {
                self: {
                    href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/commit/59721f593b020123a75424285845325126f56e2e"
                }
            }
        }, {
            hash: "56c49d8b2ae3a094fa7ba5a1251d6dd2c7c66993",
            links: {
                self: {
                    href: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/atlassian/atlassian-rest/commit/56c49d8b2ae3a094fa7ba5a1251d6dd2c7c66993"
                }
            }
        }],
        date: "2013-10-21T07:21:51+00:00",
        message: "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/rest-2.8.x' "
    }
  ],
  "page": 1
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to cut down the response data to only keys you are interested? Of am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: That is a side effect of what I'm looking for. I am looking to flatten the response object so I can have author name, message, time all at one level.  
My root issue is that for a single commit I am unable to access information such as author name because it is buried multiple layers into the json response.

Comment: 1) There isn't a programmatic way to do this, as nested Dicts could duplicate key names. 2) What language are you using to view/parse the JSON response, because Python can easily get the data you are looking for, regardless of depth. I guess I can't tell from your code what part isn't working, and what you need instead of what you are getting.

Comment: 2) I am using a python script to parse the json response. My issue arises when an array is returned. For example, 'parents' in the above sample response returns an array, and my python script interprets that as a single list within the 'values' key. I would be interested in pulling the hash values from the parent object, but python won't have keys for 'hash'.

Comment: @MarkD Where are the quotes around your json keys?

Comment: @jDo, I ripped the sample from the [bitbucket website](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/commits-or-commit-resource-389775478.html). It appears they left the double quotes off of the keys for some reason. The actual API does include double quotes areound the keys.

Comment: @MarkD Ah okay, that's why then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you're dict is missing quotes as mentioned by jDo. Assuming this is a well formed dict, you should be able to access the parent information like so:

```
parents = jd["values"][0]["parents"]
```

Then you can iterate over the parents list and do whatever you like with it:

```
for parent in parents:
    do_sth_with_parent(parent["hash"], parent["links"])
```

Does that answer the question?

Comment: FYI, the dict is not missing quotes, bitbucket was lazy when writing the documentation. I have been working simultaneously on this problem and am nearing something that looks like your help, so I believe you are correct. My issue was accessing elements within an array, and I think you nailed it.